# i18next missing key but other key was found

Tags: reactjs, react-native, i18next

I dont understand nothing anymore.

I use i18next and want to access to my key but it does not work.

```
i18next::translator: missingKey de translation profile profile
i18next::translator: missingKey de translation profile profile
i18next::translator: missingKey de translation profile profile
```

this is my translation.json

```
{
  "app_name": "Test (NEW DE)",
  "profile": "ss"
}
```

this works:

```
<Text>{ t('app_name') }</Text>
```

this not working:

```
<Text>{ t('profile') }</Text>
```

can anyone explain me why its not working correctly ?

i18next

```
import i18next from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend';

i18next
  .use(HttpApi)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    react: {
      useSuspense: false
    },
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
    lng: 'de',
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    backend: {
      loadPath: `http://192.168.0.249:4000/public/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json`,
    },
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    keySeparator: '.',
  });

export default i18next;
```

Comment: Please provide all of the i18next debug output… might be there is a problem when loading the json

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, you're calling the t function too early and are not waiting for the translations to be fully loaded.

If you're not using suspense: `useSuspense: false` you need to make sure you check for the ready flag instead.

https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook#not-using-suspense

```
// additional ready will state if translations are loaded or not
const { t, i18n, ready } = useTranslation('ns1');
```

https://react.i18next.com/latest/withtranslation-hoc#not-using-suspense

```
// use tReady prop in MyComponent to check if translations
// are already loaded or not
const ExtendedComponent = withTranslation()(MyComponent);
<ExtendedComponent />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.init({
    fallbackLng: 'fa',
    debug: false,  // add this code 
  })
```

Comment: Please add some more information to support that code snippet

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the underscore cannot be in the key name. There can't be any special characters. The name needs to be camelcase for it to work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).